# Wemos D1 Mini 8266 dynamic RAM usage

Tags: arduino-esp8266

First time posting...
I normally program using the ATMEGA 328P but have recently started using the D1 Mini ESP8266.  I have written what I consider a fairly simple program. I use PlatformIO in VSCode for the IDE.
My concern is the amount of static RAM that the program is using.

```
    Memory Stats:
    Memory region         Used Size  Region Size  %age Used
    dport0_0_seg:          0 GB         16 B      0.00%
     dram0_0_seg:       33872 B        80 KB     41.35%
     irom0_0_seg:      492260 B    1044464 B     47.13%
    **     iram1_0_seg:       27804 B        32 KB     84.85%**
    Retrieving maximum program size .pio\build\d1_mini\firmware.elf
    Checking size .pio\build\d1_mini\firmware.elf
    Advanced Memory Usage is available via "PlatformIO Home > Project Inspect"
    RAM:   [====      ]  41.3% (used 33812 bytes from 81920 bytes)
    Flash: [=====     ]  50.4% (used 526682 bytes from 1044464 bytes)
    Building .pio\build\d1_mini\firmware.bin
```

I don't seem to run into this problem on the 328P.  I am looking for some feedback on this issue or a tip or trick to reduce the IRAM usage.  PROGMEM has not been helpful.

Thanks in advance.

```
#ifndef Arduino_h
  #include <Arduino.h>
#endif

#ifndef WiFi_h
  #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#endif

#ifndef ESP_MAIL_CLIENT_H
  #include <ESP_Mail_Client.h>
#endif

#ifndef creditials_h
  #include <creditials.h>
#endif

#ifndef localWifi_h
  #include <localWifi.h>
#endif

#ifndef getTime_h
  #include <getTime.h>
#endif

#ifndef _Time_h
  #include <TimeLib.h>
#endif

#ifndef WIFIUDP_H
  #include <WiFiUdp.h>    
#endif

#ifndef global_h
  #include <global.h>
#endif

#ifndef TimFlsh_h
  #include "TimerFlasher.h"
#endif
  

// instantate methods
GetTime    M_getTime;
LocalWiFi  M_WiFi;
L_Global   M_Global;
TimFlsh    M_TimFlsh;


// global variable  
long unsigned millisSeconds = 1000; 
int  cnt = 0;
int  machHasRun                     [2]  = {_Off,  _Off };         //indicates that a mach as started
bool machAllReadyOn                 [2]  = {false, false};
int  whichMachCase                  [2]  = {  0,      0 };

/*
D3 INPUT: Washer running, pulled low when on.
D4 INPUT: Dryer running, pulled low when on.
D5 OUTPUT: pull low to turn on Washer ON LED.
D6 OUTPUT: pull low to turn on Dryer ON LED.
D7 OUTPUT: pull low to turn on Send E-mail LED.
*/

int  machOnIO                       [2]  = { D3,     D4 };         // mach on / off IO
int  machLEDIO                      [2]  = { D5,     D6 };         // LED on/off IO
int  emailLED                            =   D7;
bool wait                           [2]  = {false, false};

long unsigned OffDelayPrevMillis    [2]  = {0,0};
long unsigned OffDelayInterval      [2]  = {60 * millisSeconds, 60 * millisSeconds};

long unsigned EmailDelayPrevMillis  [2]  = {0,0};
long unsigned EmailDelayInterval    [2]  = {30 * millisSeconds, 30 * millisSeconds};
bool oneSecond                      [2]  = {true, true};
long unsigned oneSecondPrevMillis   [2]  = {0,0};
long unsigned oneSecondInterval     [2]  = {1 * millisSeconds, 1 * millisSeconds};


bool EmailOK;

//forward declare
bool SendEmail         (int cnt);

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(machOnIO[WASHER],  INPUT_PULLUP);   //washer on/off
  pinMode(machOnIO[DRYER],   INPUT_PULLUP);   //dryer on/off
  pinMode(machLEDIO[WASHER], OUTPUT);         //washer power LED
  pinMode(machLEDIO[DRYER],  OUTPUT);         // dryer LED
  pinMode(emailLED,          OUTPUT);         // sending e-mail indiacator
  

#if TEST
    pinMode(BUILTIN_LED,       OUTPUT);
      Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Setup complete:");
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,I_Off);   // turn off on board led
#endif

}  //end setup

//==========================================================================================================================
// main loop A. loop through machines to see if running
//           b. loop on case for each machine
//      case 1. start cycle, set machine to running, when detect off, prepare to delay
//      case 2. delay off of machine cycle to assure this is not a user interrupt (door opened), 
//              return to case 1 if starts running again before delay expires
//      case 3. machine confirmed off, send an e-mail.  if email fails stay in case 3, send again after delay, try 3 times
//      return to A
//==========================================================================================================================
void loop()
{  // check if a machine is running

  for (int loop = WASHER; loop <= DRYER; loop++ )            // Washer = 0, Dryer = 1
  {
    oneSecond[loop] = (M_TimFlsh.oneSecondDelay(loop, oneSecond, oneSecondPrevMillis, oneSecondInterval));  
    if (digitalRead(machOnIO[loop]) == I_On  and machAllReadyOn[loop] == false )  // machine On and not detected before
    {
      digitalWrite(machLEDIO[loop], I_On);                  // turn on proper cycle LED
      whichMachCase[loop] = START_CYCLE;                    // set switch/case
      #if TEST
        if(loop == WASHER){digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED,I_On);}        
      #endif
    } //end if
  } // end for

  //============================================================================================
  for (int loop = WASHER; loop <= DRYER; loop++ )             // check all machines
  {
        //What to do 
      //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
      switch(whichMachCase[loop])
      {
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        case START_CYCLE:  // check for end of cycle or user invocked stop
        {
          #if TEST
            Serial.println("Case START_CYCLE " + M_Global.name[loop]);
          #endif

          machAllReadyOn[loop] = true;                        // set proper machine to on
          if(digitalRead(machOnIO[loop]) == HIGH)             // ck mach off IO
          {
            OffDelayPrevMillis[loop] = millis();             // set start time for current machine for the off delay
            whichMachCase[loop] = DELAYOFF;                     // move to next case
          }
          break;
        } // END CASE Start_cycle
        
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        case DELAYOFF:  // make sure cyce is over and not just a user interruption "off delay timer"
        {
          #if TEST
            Serial.println("Case DELAYOFF " + M_Global.name[loop]);
          #endif

          if(M_TimFlsh.ckOffDelayTime(loop, OffDelayPrevMillis[loop], OffDelayInterval[loop]))                      // true when timed out
          {
            digitalWrite(machLEDIO[loop], I_Off);       // turn off cycle LED
            #if TEST
              digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED,I_Off);
            #endif
            wait[loop] = false;
            whichMachCase[loop] = SENDMAIL;             // move to next case
          }
          else if (oneSecond[loop])
          { // waiting for timeout
            machAllReadyOn[loop] = false;
            M_TimFlsh.flashLED(machLEDIO[loop]);
          }
          break;
        } // END CASE DelayOFf

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        case SENDMAIL:     // time to send the e-mail
        {
          #if TEST
            Serial.println("Case SENDEMAIL " + M_Global.name[loop]);
          #endif

          if(wait[loop])                                        // prior e-mail failed, wait to send a replacment
          {
            {wait[loop] = M_TimFlsh.ckEmailDelay(loop, EmailDelayPrevMillis[loop], OffDelayInterval[loop]);} 
          }
          else 
          {
            digitalWrite(emailLED, I_On);
            EmailOK = SendEmail(loop);
            EmailDelayPrevMillis[loop] = millis();              // set start time for e-mail delay
            if (EmailOK)
            {
                machAllReadyOn[loop] = false; 
                wait[loop] = false;
                whichMachCase[loop]  = 0;
                digitalWrite(emailLED, I_Off);
            }
              else if (!EmailOK)
            {
                M_TimFlsh.fastBlinkLED(emailLED);
                wait[loop] = true;
            }
          }
        } // END CASE SendEmail          
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        default:
        {
          break;
        } // END DEFAULT
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
      } //END SWITCH
    //====================================================================================================  
  }  // END FOR LOOP
} // end loop()

//==================================================================
// Send e-mail and get the status
//==================================================================
  bool SendEmail(int cnt)
  {
    bool EmailFail = false;
    int WiFiOK = M_WiFi.connect_WiFi();
    if (WiFiOK == WL_CONNECTED)
    {
      String Dtmsg  = M_getTime.NST_Time();
      String Emsg   = M_Global.msg[cnt];
      bool EmailOK  = M_WiFi.send_Email(Dtmsg, Emsg, "ESP8266 machine monitoring", cnt);
      if(EmailOK)
      {
        #if TEST
          Serial.println("Email OK");
        #endif
        M_WiFi.discon_Wifi();
        return EmailOK;
      }  //end  if emailOK
      else
      {
        M_WiFi.discon_Wifi();
        #if TEST
          Serial.println("Email Failed");
        #endif
        return EmailFail;
      } // end else emailok   
    }
     #if TEST
      Serial.println("Email Failed");
    #endif
    return EmailFail;
  }
```

I have tried using PROGMEM to move data into program memory.  The majority of the data is type String and the compiler will not allow their move to program memory.

Comment: you have WiFi. it is done by the esp8266

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying.  Yes, I am using WIFI to send a notification e-mail.

Comment: it takes flash space and RAM to have code to do TCP communication over WiFi. in 328p there was only your code and few Arduino core functions

Comment: "I don't seem to run into *this problem* on the 328P", what is *"this problem"* that you are referring to? ATMega328 is a 8-bit MCU, ESP8266 is 32-bit MCU, even for the same blinking memory, they will have different memory utilisation, not mentioned that your sketch included many library that simply not generally used in ATmega328 arduino. PROGMEM is specific for AVR-based architecture, to keep variables in the flash for ESP8266, you just need to declare it as `const`, and this apply to String too, see [PROGMEM](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PROGMEM.html).

Comment: "My concern is the amount of static RAM that the program is using".  As stated in the original post.  Thanks for the reply.